How many esims can be *stored* on an iPhone SE3 (i.e. as well as 2 active sims)
I believe 2 e-sims can be active and 8 e-sims can be stored (i.e. to include e-sims that are not currently activated on the phone) depending on the iPhone model. Presumably the user would select 2 of these to be the active e-sims.
If 8 e-sims could be stored, then I would assume that 2 of those e-sims can be selected as active and the other 6 were inactive.
An accepted answer will be one that provides a direct link the apple.com documentation stating if more than 2 e-sims can be stored on the iPhone SE3 but not activated.
What should I expect for an iPhone SE 3?

What search results have you been reading that are not the official Apple docs on the matter? Surely this wouldn't have been so hard to find? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/118669

You can create the documentation yourself by trying it and posting your results here.

+1 thank you @Linc Davis I often do that with my questions on StackExchange sites. I will endeavour to do so.

@AndyGriffiths +1 for the link, I was looking for 8 numeral not eight as a word, I've found it. That answers my question. As this link is posted in the answer below, I have accepted it.

Would appreciate reasons for the downvotes from those doing them.  I've accepted a) the answer as it provides a link to an Apple doc that says: "You can install eight [8] or more eSIMs on an iPhone and use two phone numbers at the same time."  b) given the negative votes that's all I want to spend my time on with this question. I would hope that the question and answer provided are helpful to others. Thank you everyone for their time. Thank you.

I think the down votes were saying research was done and not linking as well as some chit-chat the site eschews.. Hopefully the edit and check selecting an answer will let others see value in the post

Apple doesn’t specify a maximum, which typically means not a problem they need to solve for the vast majority of people.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/118669


You can install eight or more eSIMs on an iPhone and use two phone numbers at the same time.

At the bottom of the page is a link to Apple support if you have a problem only they can answer (like why is it eight or more…)

I’d start with your carrier since they are in the driver seat for how many sim they will accommodate for every single cellular device when it’s trying to talk on the cellular radio frequencies.
Also be aware carriers may be keeping things vague to address abuse of account switching which seems the likely limit here for inactive sim on a device not even using a sim.

Apple implements 100+ private relay email aliases and 100 eSIM seems a trivial amount of programming. They also work closely with carriers, but don’t often speak for them.
Of for some reason you don’t trust Apple and your carrier, I’d work with a reputable vendor like Airolo rather than trust volunteers here like me. :)

+1 upvote and accepted. That link provided, https://support.apple.com/en-us/118669, answers my question: "You can install eight [8] or more eSIMs on an iPhone and use two phone numbers at the same time."  Thank you also for the other information. That's everything I need. I'll leave it there.

So glad @therobyouknow - it's always humbling to realize how diverse everyone's experience and knowledge domains are here. Something that one person sees as obvious can be so far afield of another's deep experience and knowledge of adjacent topics. Not knowing and asking is the power move. Thanks for the tick and confirmation this was what you needed.
